# Should we release NSDate manually?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I declared NSDate at my header file with following configuration:

```
# TestController.h
@interface TestController : UITableViewController{
    NSDate      *selectedDate;
    NSManagedObject *task;
}
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *managedObject;
    @property (retain) NSDate *selectedDate 
@end

# TestController.m
@implementation TestController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        self.selectedDate = [managedObject valueForKey:@"title"];
    }
    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        self.task = nil;
        self.selectedDate = nil;
    }

    - (void)dealloc {
        [self.task release]
      [self.selectedDate release];
      [super dealloc];
    }
@end
```

For my understanding, you should release variables that is alloc, copy or retain. As I retain the variable data here, so I release when dealloc. But, end up throw memory deallocation error:

"[**NSDate isNSDate**]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6923750"

If I didn't manually release it, its working fine. My question is should I release the variable for this scenario?

**Update:**

Did an instrument test with zombie templates and this is the output:

```
#   Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   __NSDate    Malloc  1   1331055104  0x895e9d0   16  CoreData    -[NSSQLCore _prepareResultsFromResultSet:usingFetchPlan:withMatchingRows:]
1   __NSDate    Retain  2   1333056000  0x895e9d0   0   Task    -[TaskViewCell configureData:]
2   __NSDate    Retain  3   3045008128  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _newPropertiesForRetainedTypes:andCopiedTypes:preserveFaults:]
3   __NSDate    Retain  4   3054921984  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSSQLRow copy]
4   __NSDate    Release 3   3059244032  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSSQLOperation dealloc]
5   __NSDate    Release 2   3059607040  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 dealloc]
6   __NSDate    Retain  3   3715918848  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _newPropertiesForRetainedTypes:andCopiedTypes:preserveFaults:]
7   __NSDate    Retain  4   3727657984  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSSQLRow copy]
8   __NSDate    Release 3   3730131200  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSSQLOperation dealloc]
9   __NSDate    Release 2   3730286080  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 dealloc]
10  __NSDate    Retain  3   4250617856  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _newPropertiesForRetainedTypes:andCopiedTypes:preserveFaults:]
11  __NSDate    Retain  4   4250759936  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:]
12  __NSDate    Release 3   4250761984  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:]
13  __NSDate    Retain  4   4260489984  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSSQLRow copy]
14  __NSDate    Release 3   4263536896  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSSQLOperation dealloc]
15  __NSDate    Release 2   4263687168  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 dealloc]
16  __NSDate    Release 1   4656624128  0x895e9d0   0   Task    -[TaskEditController dealloc]
17  __NSDate    Retain  2   7570179840  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _newPropertiesForRetainedTypes:andCopiedTypes:preserveFaults:]
18  __NSDate    Retain  3   7570360064  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:]
19  __NSDate    Release 2   7570361088  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:]
20  __NSDate    Retain  3   7577499136  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSSQLRow copy]
21  __NSDate    Release 2   7602608128  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSSQLOperation dealloc]
22  __NSDate    Release 1   7602752256  0x895e9d0   0   CoreData    -[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 dealloc]
23  __NSDate    Release 0   7971558144  0x895e9d0   0   Task    -[TaskEditController dealloc]
24  __NSDate    Zombie  -1  9697122048  0x895e9d0   0   Foundation  -[NSDateFormatter stringForObjectValue:]
```

Didn't really understand what this mean. But, my guess is coredata releasing the NSDate even with retain?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to troubleshoot a problem with over-releasing an object is to fire up Instruments (from within XCode, type ⌘-I instead of ⌘-R) and choose the "Zombies" template – it'll show you where each object is being retained and released, and tell you when your code sends a message to an already-released instance.

It's possible in this case that an unbalanced release is lurking somewhere else in your code, and putting a release in your dealloc method is exposing a problem that lies elsewhere. In any case, the direct answer to your question is "yes, you should be releasing the variable you retained," and the code you've posted here has the correct ratio of retains to releases (that is, one to one), so I'd look for other places where you might be releasing this NSDate.

Comment: Well, have a quick search on project and not finding any place releasing the date object. I was getting the date object from ManageObject and I releasing it as well. Will this cause problem? I updated my code, will try your method shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Calling `[ self.selectedDate release ]` will decrement the retain count of the object in `self.selectedDate`, however self.selectedDate still contains a reference to the (now over-released) date object.

You should do this:

`self.selectedDate = nil`.

Because:

`self.selectedDate = nil`

is convenient syntax for this actual code:

`[ self setSelectedDate:nil ]`

The method `setSelectedDate:` is automatically generated by

`@synthesize selectedDate`.

Since the property is declared `retain`, the generated setter looks like this:

```
-(void)setSelectedDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    [ selectedDate release ] ; // refers to the generated selectedDate instance variable in this class
    selectedDate = [ date retain ] ;
}
```

Finally if you don't need atomic access (which you don't in most cases), use this `nonatomic` declaration instead:

```
@property ( nonatomic, retain ) NSDate * date
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. I have updated my question to better illustrate my code. I did set my date object to nil for clearing reference. I try on your nonatomic declaration too, but so far no luck.

Comment: btw--viewDidUnload is not always called. It will only be called in low memory situations when your view is unloaded. Anyway, the code in dealloc should still be changed to `self.selectedDate = nil`

Comment: In that case I would try Instruments as Scott Forbes suggested. (Use the Allocations instrument--you will be able to see the entire retain/release/autorelease/alloc history for each NSDate in your program. The problem should jump out right away.

Comment: Did try out. I have updated the post with the log, sounds like coredata releasing NSDate.

Comment: (I wouldn't suspect Core Data unless you are 100% sure.) Looks like `[ TestController dealloc ]` is being executing twice. That should never happen. You are over-releasing TestController, but before that can cause troubles, you are hitting this problem. Check your TestController retain/release

Comment: Reason [TestController dealloc] is calling twice is because the app only crash when I traverse between RootViewController and TestController for several times. I did some checking, [TestController release] only called once. Hmm..strange.

Comment: Did you call dealloc directly anywhere?

Comment: Yeah. I did call dealloc from viewWillAppear of RootViewController, but I checked before it re-released again. if (testController) {
 [testController release];
 testController = nil;
}

Comment: you mean you called `release` not `dealloc`, right? You should not call `dealloc`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should release any variable that you own (alloced, copied or retained). However, the proper way to release your NSDate variable in dealloc method should be either:

```
[selectedDate release];
selectedDate = nil;
```

OR

```
self.selectedDate = nil;
```

The second approach will call the selector method of property which first releases the variable and then assign nil to the handler. So, this one line of code will both release it and set it to nil like the two separate lines in the first option.

Comment: Setting your pointer to nil will not release it, the reference still exists.

Comment: Is this comment about the first or second approach?

Comment: Ok, my understanding for a property with retain is; by using self with the property will call its setter method and release the old value first, no? Doesn't it work like this?- (void) setVarid) newValue {
if (var != newValue) {
[var release];
var = newValue;
[newValue retain];
}
} ?

Comment: upvote. using `self.selectedDate = nil` is correct. This is equivalent to [ self setSelectedDate:nil ]. The generated setter (`setSelectedDate:`) will release the existing object upon set, since the property is declared `retain`

Comment: @Imran I apologize, you're right that the default setter will release the old memory, I misunderstood what you'd written. I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[selectedDate release];
```

Instead of

```
[self.selectedDate release];
```

Comment: No. The error caused by the variables has been release before, but I only release on the class dealloc method.